# Delete files which are not locked (in use)

Tags: powershell, delete-file, filelock

I'm trying to delete all files (not folders) in `%TEMP%` which are older than 30 days. The problem is that some files are in use by a program so they can not be deleted. I tried to solve the problem as follow:

```
   function IsFileLocked($filePath){
        #write-host $filePath

        Rename-Item $filePath $filePath -ErrorVariable errs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $errs.Count
        if ($errs.Count -ne 0)
        {
            return $true #File is locked
        }
        else 
        {
            return $false #File is not locked  
        }
    }

 $Path= "$env:temp"
    if ((Test-Path -Path $Path) -ieq $true) 
    {
    $Daysback =  '-30'
    $CurrentDate = Get-Date
    $DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback) 

    get-childitem $Path -recurse  | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime  -lt $DatetoDelete } | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False }| Where-Object {(IsFileLocked -filePath "($_)") -eq $false }# | remove-item   -force #-WhatIf
    }
```

The problem is that (`IsFileLocked -filePath "($_)") -eq $false` doesn't return any element.

Is it possible that `get-childitem` blocks the files, so that all of them are locked when I run `get-childitem`?

Any other ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just removing files older than 30 days and ignore the errors:

```
$old = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

Get-ChildItem $env:TEMP -Recurse | 
Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $old } | 
Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the better way!